# isomorphic-fetch and redux-saga, how to call it properly ? how to manage it with generators?

Tags: redux, fetch, react-redux, redux-saga

It tells me "promise is not a function". My problem is that with isomorphic fetch you have to put twice then to get your parsed result. What should I do to manage that properly with redux-saga generators ?

```
import { put, call, takeEvery, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
import errorMessages from './../conf/errorMessages'

function *fetchBalances(address) {
    try {
        var request = fetch('/api/getBalances/rJnZ4YHCUsHvQu7R6mZohevKJDHFzVD6Zr').then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }). then(function(result) {
            // finally my parsed result !
            return result;
        });
        const balances = yield call(request)
        yield put({ type: 'GET_BALANCES_SUCCEED', balances: balances})
    }
    catch(error) {
        yield put({ type: 'GET_BALANCES_ERROR', error: error })
    }
}

export function* watchGetBalances() {
    yield takeEvery('GET_BALANCES', fetchBalances);
}
```

I could put that in a closure but is that the best idea ? =/

```
var request = function() {
            return fetch('/api/getBalances/rJnZ4YHCUsHvQu7R6mZohevKJDHFzVD6Zr').then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }). then(function(result) {
                return result;
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The confusion here comes from the fact that the `request` variable that you're passing to the `call` effect holds a `Promise`. What you want, is the `call` effect to execute that Promise for you.

In other words, you have already manually called the `fetch` function, instead of passing `call` a function that will call and return it.

So, yes, wrapping your fetch calls in a, eg. `callRequest` function could be useful but if you do so,  you must be careful to write `const response = yield call(callRequest)`, and not `const response = yield call(callRequest())`, which would be equivalent to what you wrote.

A few precisions, in case it helps. From the docs, `call` receives as its first argument:

> A Generator function, or normal function which either returns a Promise as result, or any other value.

Let's see how that works.

First a generator function.

```
const response = yield call(myFunction);

function* myFunction() {
  yield delay(1000);
  return true;
}

// response === true
```

Then a function returning some value (not the most useful, but…)

```
const response = yield call(myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  return true;
}

// response === true;
```

Finally a function returning a Promise

```
const response = yield call(callRequest);

function callRequest() {
  return fetch(…).then( r => r.json() )
}

// response holds your data
// if the Promise were to be rejected, you could catch
// the error in a try-catch block
```